# CUDA result returns garbage using very large array, but reports no error

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nvidia

I am creating a test program that will create a device and a host array of size *n* and then launch a kernel that creates *n* threads which allocate the constant value 0.95f to each location in the device array. After completion, the device array is copied to the host array and all entries are totaled and a final total is displayed.

The program below seems to work fine for array sizes up to around 60 million floats and returns the correct results very quickly, but upon reaching 70 million the program seems to hang for a while and eventually returns a NAN result for the total. Inspecting the host array after a 60 million run shows it is correctly populated with 0.95f, but inspecting it after a 70 million run shows it is populated with NAN. As far as I am aware none of the CUDA calls return errors.

I am using a 2GB GT640m (Compute 3.0), giving me a max block size of 1024 and a max grid dimension of 2147483647.

I am sure there are better ways of achieving something similar, and I would like to hear suggestions. But I would also like to understand what has gone wrong here so I can learn from it.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

void cudaErrorHandler(cudaError_t status)
{
    // Cuda call returned an error, just print error for now
    if(status != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }
}

__global__ void addKernel(float* _Results, int _TotalCombinations)
{
    // Get thread Id
    unsigned int Id = (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockIdx.x) + (blockDim.x * threadIdx.y) + threadIdx.x;

    //If the Id is within simulation range, log it
    if(Id < _TotalCombinations)
    {
        _Results[Id] = 0.95f;
    }
}

#define BLOCK_DIM_X 32
#define BLOCK_DIM_Y 32
#define BLOCK_SIZE BLOCK_DIM_X * BLOCK_DIM_Y // Statc block size of 32*32 (1024)
#define CUDA_CALL(x) cudaErrorHandler(x)

int main()
{
    // The number of simulations to run
    unsigned int totalCombinations = 45000000;

    int gridsize = 1;

    // Work out how many blocks of size 1024 are required to perform all of totalCombinations
    for(unsigned int totalsize = gridsize * BLOCK_SIZE; totalsize < totalCombinations; 
        gridsize++, totalsize = gridsize * BLOCK_SIZE)
        ;

    // Allocate host memory
    float* host_results = new float[totalCombinations];
    memset(host_results, 0, sizeof(float) * totalCombinations);
    float *dev_results = 0;

    cudaSetDevice(0);

    // Allocate device memory
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_results, totalCombinations * sizeof(float)));

    dim3 grid, block;

    block = dim3(BLOCK_DIM_X, BLOCK_DIM_Y);

    grid = dim3(gridsize);

    // Launch kernel
    addKernel<<<gridsize, block>>>(dev_results, totalCombinations);

    // Wait for synchronize
    CUDA_CALL(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    // Copy device data back to host
    CUDA_CALL(cudaMemcpy(host_results, dev_results, totalCombinations * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    double total = 0.0;

    // Total the results in the host array
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < totalCombinations; i++)
        total+=host_results[i];

    // Print results to screen
    printf("Total %f\n", total);

    delete[] host_results;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your error handling method is not working.  To prove this, change your block dim x and y to 50 (yielding 2500 threads, which is illegal) and you get no error printed out.  If you fix your error handling, you will discover the problem.  The reason things are not working at your failure point is that your gridsize (you are launching a 1D grid) is exceeding the maximum grid size in the X dimension (65535 by default).  If you want to take advantage of the larger gridsize, you need to compile with the `-arch=sm_30` switch.  Another note, you have a block X dimension of 22, that is not recommended.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I corrected my error checking (and the block X, that was a typo on my part) and then added the switch to the command line and this has solved my problems and everything is running correctly.
If you wish to submit this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you've discovered, your error handling method is not working.  Below I have pasted a version of your code with an error checking method that I use frequently.  The reason things are not working at your failure point is that your gridsize (you are launching a 1D grid) is exceeding the maximum grid size in the X dimension (65535 by default, ie. for compute capability up to 2.x). If you want to take advantage of a larger gridsize dimension (2^31 -1 is limit with compute capability 3.0), you need to compile with the `-arch=sm_30` switch.

Just for reference here is a version of your code which shows an error-checking method that I use frequently.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>


#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__global__ void addKernel(float* _Results, int _TotalCombinations)
{
    // Get thread Id
    unsigned int Id = (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockIdx.x) + (blockDim.x * threadIdx.y) + threadIdx.x;

    //If the Id is within simulation range, log it
    if(Id < _TotalCombinations)
    {
        _Results[Id] = 0.95f;
    }
}

#define BLOCK_DIM_X 32
#define BLOCK_DIM_Y 32
#define BLOCK_SIZE BLOCK_DIM_X * BLOCK_DIM_Y // Statc block size of 32*32 (1024)

int main()
{
    // The number of simulations to run
    unsigned int totalCombinations = 65000000;

    int gridsize = 1;

    // Work out how many blocks of size 1024 are required to perform all of totalCombinations
    for(unsigned int totalsize = gridsize * BLOCK_SIZE; totalsize < totalCombinations;
        gridsize++, totalsize = gridsize * BLOCK_SIZE)
        ;
    printf("gridsize = %d, blocksize = %d\n", gridsize, BLOCK_SIZE);
    // Allocate host memory
    float* host_results = new float[totalCombinations];
    memset(host_results, 0, sizeof(float) * totalCombinations);
    float *dev_results = 0;

    cudaSetDevice(0);

    // Allocate device memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_results, totalCombinations * sizeof(float));
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail");

    dim3 grid, block;

    block = dim3(BLOCK_DIM_X, BLOCK_DIM_Y);

    grid = dim3(gridsize);

    // Launch kernel
    addKernel<<<gridsize, block>>>(dev_results, totalCombinations);
    cudaCheckErrors("kernel fail");
    // Wait for synchronize
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaCheckErrors("sync fail");

    // Copy device data back to host
    cudaMemcpy(host_results, dev_results, totalCombinations * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy 2 fail");

    double total = 0.0;

    // Total the results in the host array
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < totalCombinations; i++)
        total+=host_results[i];

    // Print results to screen
    printf("Total %f\n", total);

    delete[] host_results;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, in future I will use this error checking method.

Comment: great answer. helped me even today. Thank you!